# Swift iOS MetalKit draw a curve , why the end of the curve is always in the center, how can i fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, metalkit

Swift 4.2, iOS 12.1, Xcode 10.1

I try to use the MetalKit to draw a curve/line on the screen.

Here is some relative code my Renderer class.

```
//TWO Points here
var vertices: [Float] = [
    0.7, 0.7 , 0.0,
    0.7, 0.8, 0.0
]

//maker buffer
vertexBuffer = device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices, length: vertices.count * MemoryLayout<Float>.size, options: [])


commandEncoder?.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder?.drawPrimitives(type: .lineStrip , vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: vertices.count)
```

Here is my Shader.metal code.

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

vertex float4 vertex_shader(const device packed_float3 *vertices [[ buffer(0) ]], uint vertexId [[vertex_id]]){

    return float4(vertices[vertexId], 1);
}

fragment half4 fragment_shader(){

    return half4(1, 0, 0, 1);

}
```

but final I got this, look at the picture.
Why it is always end in the center of the screen , how can I fix it ?
[image]

by the way, is there any good tutorial of MetalKit to learn?

Answer (score 1):

`vertices.count` is 6, the number of `Float`s in it. I think you're expecting it to be 2.

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. The `vertexCount` property of `drawPrimitives` should be `2` instead of result of `vertices.count`